# Error while unzipping: need PK compat. v5.1 (can do v4.6)

Tags: error-handling, unzip

I am getting this error while unzipping a file how unzip it

```
c0mrad3@dinp:~/output/zip$ unzip 00000018.zip 
Archive:  00000018.zip
   skipping: secret.txt              need PK compat. v5.1 (can do v4.6)
```

Comment: Answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183452/error-trying-to-unzip-file-need-pk-compat-v6-1-can-do-v4-6) too.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Try installing 7z `sudo apt-get install p7zip-full` and then extract the file with it `7z x 00000018.zip`

Comment: +1 for this, thanks for the command some reason p7zip -d doesn't like my .zip file. after using 7z x [file], it prompted me to enter the password required and extracted the file nicely.

Comment: +1 i used `7z x datafile.zip -aoa -p$3CR37` with success. Argument `-p******` is the password, `-aoa` allows extraction over any existing local files.

Comment: 7z is it, what I needed to unzip my password protected .zip...!

Comment: The solution is absolutely correct, but there's one addition: The files will be placed in your home folder ( /home/yourname/files ) and you might have to change the permission settings. In terminal : chown yourname ./filename(s) or just chown yourname ./ -R, since all the other files must be yours anyway.